# Double socketIO event bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, debugging, socket.io

I am working on a quiz app. I have a bug wich keeps me busy for 4 hours now. 
I am trying to use socketIO in my app. Players can post their answer to the quiz master. The quiz master can view them on his personal page. The problem is that when I submit an answer as player the socket.on() on the quiz master's side triggers twice.

Getting the answers from the database and then from socket (I think this is where the problem is):

```
 $http.get('/api/antwoorden/' + $scope.linkHash)
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $scope.answers = data.doc.ingezonden;
                            console.log("****GEZONDEN VAN DATABASE****", $scope.answers)
                            var i = 0;
                            socketIO.on('answerSend', function (object) {
                                i = i + 1;
                                console.log(i);
                                if(object.uitvoering === $scope.myCode) {
                                    $scope.answers.push(object.answer);
                                    console.log("***", object);
                                }
                                console.log("*****NU IS DIE DIT*****", $scope.answers);
                            });
                        });
```

console output

[image: console output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everytime you run the `$http.get`, you're adding a new copy of this event handler:

```
socketIO.on('answerSend', function (object) ...
```

So, after running it twice, you'll have double event handlers.  After running it three times, triple event handlers and so on.  You need to make sure an event handler is only ever added once.

I don't know the overall structure of your code, but I would guess that you want to add the event handler outside of the http response code so it is just added once.